# Show Error From Controllers in React Hook Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to throw required errors from my input which I have wrapped in a Controller component from `react-hook-form` version 7.

My Input is a Material-UI TextField as such;

```
<Controller
                        
    name="firstName"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    rules={{ required: true}}
    render={({field}) =>
        <TextField
        id="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        autoComplete="fname"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        label="First Name"
        autoFocus={true}
        {...field} />
    }
/>
```

I would like to expose an error when rules fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass the property of the `errors` object matching your field name to your Material UI `<TextField />`. The `errors` object is available via the `formState` property.

```js
const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
```

You should also pass the `ref` to the `inputRef` prop instead of setting it to the `ref` prop. This will automatically focus the `<TextField />` input if there is an error on submit.

```
<Controller
  name="firstName"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      inputRef={ref}
      id="firstName"
      autoComplete="fname"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      error={!!errors.firstName}
      label="First Name"
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - MUI Autocomplete (forked)]

Comment: Save me two days!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

What @knoefel is saying is working. Something else you can do is using the `fieldState`. See official documentation [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller).

```html
<Controller
  name="firstName"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState: {invalid, error} }) => (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      inputRef={ref}
      id="firstName"
      autoComplete="fname"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      error={invalid}
      label="First Name"
    />
  )}
/>
```

Then with `error` you would get the error object. So you could use `{error?.message}` to display the error message.

Comment: Here, `invalid` is a boolean, whereas `error?.message` would have the actual text of the error. Just FYI for others. So, if error should be bool in this code it would be fine, but if error is supposed to be the error text to show a user, you'd want to get that from the `error.message` prop.